# Delete all comments in C# code using TextPad 'Find And Replace' using Regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex, comments, replace, textpad

I want to get rid of all comments in a C# file using a TextPad regular expression, using the Find And Replace feature.  I don't need one regular expression to do this.  I don't mind making multiple passes.

Scenarios:

If C# source code line contains code, remove the white spaces and comments after the code.  If the C# source code line(s) contains no actual code, remove the entire line(s).

```
 x = y;  /* comment on single line */

 x = y;  // comment on single line

 x = y;  /* comment on multiple lines
            comment on multiple lines */
```

Are there any I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/)! First of all, make sure you are using POSIX syntax (go to Configure > Preferences > Editor and enable "use POSIX regular expression syntax").

Indeed, you will need several passes:

1. Replace `\/\*+.*\*+\/` for nothing.
2. Replace `\/\/+.*$` for nothing.
3. Replace `\/\*+.*$` for nothing.
4. Replace `^.*\*+\/\b*$` for nothing.

This will also remove something like:

```
/*** comment on single line ***/
```

or

```
//// comment on single line
```

It may be a good idea to record a macro so you can remove comments with a single click. There's are macros for commenting and uncommenting Javascript code that should work with C# code as well: http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/macros.html

Comment: thanks dude!!  Me too!  I used to write these regular expressions all the time back in college, but I lost my arsenal (or misplaced it in my stack of CDs).  I never heard about the POSIX syntax before.

Comment: I just checked and they seem to work without enabling POSIX syntax.

Comment: In these expressions, remove all the `+`s, they are completely useless. And you need a `?` after the first `.*`, and you can remove all the `$` (if `.` doesn't match new lines, if it does you need to ungreedy all those quantifiers instead). And `\b*`? What do you mean with that? It makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex pattern: (/*([^]|[\r\n]|(*+([^/]|[\r\n])))*+/)|(//.)

see more https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-find-code-comments-9d1f7a29/